# Encrypt a wordpress plugin's submenu page with SSL

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I added a submenu page for my plugin in the admin panel. I have FORCE_SSL_ADMIN and FORCE_SSL_LOGIN set to true in wp-config.php. When I went to my plugin's submenu page, I found that it is only "partially encrypted". But every wordpress' own menu/submenu page is fully encrypted except for the Dashboard.

Why isn't the Dashboard fully encrypted?
How can I encrypt my plugin's submenu page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do the following two things before FORCE_SSL_ADMIN began to work:

1. move the define statement to a place in wp-config.php BEFORE where it calls wp-settings.php
2. configure Apache's SSL setup to include an alias that points to the non-SSL location of the wordpress directory